# using Interfaces instead of Concrete class mapping a HashMap in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have an interface called Person as below

```
public interface Person {
    String getName();}
```

I have an abstract class, AbstractPerson which implement Person. Abstar

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PERSON_TYPE")
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class AbstractPerson implements Person{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
.....
@Override
public String getName() {

    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

My concrete class is Member so it extends AbstractPerson.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="MEMBER")
public class Member extends AbstractPerson{ 

@OneToMany(mappedBy="commentOwner")
@MapKey(name="id" )
private Map<Long, CommentImpl> commentList;
 ....
```

The code that creates the ManyToOne relation in CommentImpl is below

```
public class CommentImpl implements Comment, Serializable{
@ManyToOne
private Member commentOwner;
....
```

My problem is I want to write the code against interfaces instead of concrete class. So The value type in HashMap will be Comment in Member class and the commentOwner will be Person type in CommentImpl class. 
When I do that, I get a unknowm mapping exception. How can I set this relationship with interfaces and concrete classes?

Comment: Can you update your question to show how `Member` implements `Person` (e.g. through `AbstractPerson` which implements `Person`)?

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback! I also added AbstractPerson code

Answer (score 1):

The `one-to-many` side becomes:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="commentOwner", targetEntity = "CommentImpl.class")
@MapKey(name="id" )
private Map<Long, Comment> commentList;
```

and the `many-to-one` side should be:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Member.class")
private Person commentOwner;
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution but I have another question regarding to that solution.

Say that I write another concrete class, Member2, implementing Person interface. It has the same relationship with Comment entity. How will I introduce another targetEntity within CommentImpl class then?

1- Can I use @Any annotations?
2- Can I move that relationship to the AbstractClass?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not exactly I am looking for. What if I write another concrete class That implements the interface Person?